# Cannot integrate $I = \int \frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)}dx$

Tags: integration

I can't evaluate this integral:
$$I = \int \frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)}dx$$ 
Please help.

Comment: You're going to need polylogarithms for this…

Comment: @Parchy Taxel what is that?

Comment: What do you need to solve this for? This integral is the indefinite version of $2F_2(0)$, where $F_j(x)$ is the complete Fermi-Dirac Integral. I would imagine that for any situation where you would need to solve this, you would have already learned about the notion of a polylogarithm. It cannot be expressed with elementary functions.

Comment: @infinitylord Please be descriptive.....i dont underdtand what are you telling...im a Btech !st year student....dont know much....

Comment: What I'm saying is that this integral cannot be solved using functions that you would learn about in a typical undergraduate calculus course. I am curious as to *why* you are seeking its solution. The solution depends on polylogarithms, as Parcly Taxel said.

Comment: Actually in a our Engineering Physics text book the definite form is used limit is from 0 to infinity. Now i wanted to know how it came..

Comment: With the limits from $0$ to $\infty$, the integral *is* the complete Fermi-Dirac Integral I mentioned above. I recommend looking into that and the Fermi-Dirac Distribution for a derivation. Solving the integral itself will not be possible without a larger set of tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for $X>0$, by letting $t=kx$,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^X \frac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx&=\int_0^X  \frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx=\int_0^X x^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-kx}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}\int_0^{kX}  t^2 e^{-t}dt 
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}[(2+2t+t^2)e^{-t}]_{kX}^0\\
&=2\zeta(3)-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-X})^k}{k^3}
-2X\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-X})^k}{k^2}
-X^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-X})^k}{k}\\
&=2\zeta(3)-2\text{Li}_3(e^{-X})
-2X\text{Li}_2(e^{-X})
+X^2\ln(1-e^{-X})
\end{align}$$
where $\text{Li}_s(z)$ is the $s$-th [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).